# Can't override list.phtml in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2, catalog, theme-fallback, list.phtml

I'm trying to override Magento_Catalog list.phtml in magento 2.1.6 and it's not working. I have a theme working and others templates and layouts overrides are working correctly.

My custom list.phtml is here:

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml
```

If I remove "category.product.list" in my "catalog_category_view.xml" in

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout
```

with this funcion:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" remove="true" />
```

product grid disappears.

I've tried also to disable modules but it's not working.

I'm doing tests modifying list.phtml line 68 link class:

```
    <a class="product-item-link test"
```

And in my grid isn't showing this change.

Comment: Check if any module is overriding this phtml and taking preference over theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when doing reference for removing it works , i m guessing that you are using the current active theme.

Make sure you are in developer mode and then I would try to clean pub/static and var/view_preprocessed and redeploy static content. If this doesn't work try and extend the layout.
In app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
......
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
...... rest of file depending on what you are extending
```

I had to extend ListProduct.php for different reasons so i don't know if it works with default but this is working for me.

Comment: Overriding block by XML it's working. But I changed:

`<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" ....`

for:

`<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"`

because I don't have any module overriding ListProduct.php

Answer (score 0):

To override a template you only need to move it into your theme, the XML you have written is removing the template so it will no longer be rendered.

Remove the line with `remove="true"` and clear cache and Magento should use your template.

Comment: XML update it's a test. It's only for check the template overriding it's working. The problem is with list.phtm.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove block than you cant use same block for custom list file.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" remove="true" />
```

so you have to use this Layout with your custom block name and custom-list.phtml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list.custom" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/custom-catalog-list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```